# Loading java object when parsing xml using SAX xerces

Tags: java, xerces

If my xml looks like:

```
<root version="1.1">
  <node number="1">
    <url>http://....</url>
  </node>
  <url>http://...</url>
</root>
```

Now in my endElement event I look if the xml element starts with 'url', **but how do I know when the `url` element is the url element inside the `node` element and when it is not?**

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
  if(qName.equals("url")) {
    someObject.setUrl(characters);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to keep track of elements "seen" either by maintaining a stack of element names or using a flag that indicates you're inside of a  subtree.

First way: in startElement push the element name on a stack, then in endElement pop the name off the stack.  When you see "url" in endElement, check if "node" is on the stack.

Another way: in startElement set nodeElementSeen = true, then in endElement set nodeElementSeen = false.  When you see "url" in endElement, check if nodeElementSeen = true.